# Probability Rolling a dice until you get 1/2 or 2/2

Tags: probability, dice

You roll $1$ die repeatedly until you get a $1$ immediately followed by a $2$ or a $2$ immediately followed by a $2$.

What is the probability that a $1$ then a $2$ is rolled before a $2$ then a $2$?

#### Progress

At first I thought they were equally likely.  I thought "if you roll a 1 then you have a 1/6 chance of rolling a 2... and same thing with you roll a 2 you have a 1/6 chance of rolling another 2.." but then i realized that rolling a 1 means that if you roll a 2 that 2 doesn't count to rolling another 2. I.e. the 1/2 outcome cuts into the 2/2 outcome so its some dependence going on and I don't know how to account for that.

Comment: What have you done?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Er, I mean, show us your calculations, your progress so that we can help you.

Comment: Ummm I don't even know where to begin... At first I thought they were equally likely. Like I thought "if you roll a 1 then you have a 1/6 chance of rolling a 2... and same thing with you roll a 2 you have a 1/6 chance of rolling another 2.. but then i realized that rolling a 1 means that if you roll a 2 that 2 doesn't count to rolling another 2. I.e. the 1/2 outcome cuts into the 2/2 outcome so its some dependence going on and I don't know how to account for that.

Comment: @MauroAugusto: You have nicely identified a subtle dependence.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a$ be the required probability. Call it the probability that we (ultimately) *win*.  It is reasonably clear that $a$ exists.

Let $b$ be the probability  we (ultimately) win 
given that a $1$ has just been rolled. Let $c$ be the probability we (ultimately) win given a $2$ has just been rolled (and we have not just lost).

We condition on the result of the first toss. Suppose it is  something other than $1$ or $2$. Then the probability we win is $a$.

If the first result is $1$, then by definition the probability we win 
is $b$.

If the result is $2$, then the probability is $c$. Thus
$$a=\frac{4}{6}a+\frac{1}{6}b+\frac{1}{6}c.\tag{1}$$

Now suppose a $1$ has just been rolled. If we next roll anything but $1$ or $2$, the probability we win is $a$. If we roll a $1$, the probability we win is $a$, and if we roll a $2$ then we have won,  the probability is $1$. Thus
$$b=\frac{4}{6}a+\frac{1}{6}b+\frac{1}{6}.\tag{2}$$

Suppose finally that we have just rolled a $2$ (and not lost). An argument similar to the previous two shows that
$$c=\frac{4}{6}a+\frac{1}{6}b.\tag{3}$$

Solve the system of three linear equations in three unknowns. We get $a=\dfrac{7}{12}$.

**Remark:** The problem is really a Markov chain problem, with three states, "neutral," "just rolled a $1$," and "just rolled a non-losing $2$." There is a natural transition matrix, closely related to our three equations.